# Fixed ACPI Description Table flags information

Tags: windows

I'm wondering how to get flags infromation from ACPI [FADT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn495660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#fadt) (Fixed ACPI Description Table) under Windows? Is there a tool or program-way?

Actually, I need to detect is there "LOW_POWER_S0_IDLE_CAPABLE" flag in that table.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain any information from ACPI tables using these [tools](https://www.acpica.org/downloads/binary-tools) (sources are included).

Example (getting what I need):

```
acpidump -b -n FACP.dat
iasl -d FACP.dat
```

Next we get FACP.dsl that contains the flag:

```
Low Power S0 Idle (V5) : 0
```